# DefaultHandler class in android doesnt read entire string from xml

Tags: java, android, string, polyline

I am extending DefaultHandler to parse an xml.
I am parsing this page:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=staten%20island&destination=florida&sensor=false

I am getting all the polyline>points.
Everything works fine except for one specific string.
I am overriding the characters method in DefaultHandler like this:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
if (currentElement) {
    Log.v("Length", length+"");
    currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
    currentElement = false;
    }

}
```

The length returns 282 when the string is 660 characters long.
This is the string:

qhitFxpifMn@t@vA`CdM`WnnBjeEtI|PlIxNxHhMjLdQ|dAlwA`~CxfEfOxRlK`O~PdUvOlTnHdJbYl\fVlW`q@~p@~gA`gAfKzKbP`Rpa@bi@|wAnuBjZ|c@rD~F`JjP|I|Qzr@`~AbKpS`J~OvGdKnPhUbMpN~{@~{@tLhMlZfZnI~Ilh@nh@nN`O~GbJjEpGpErHbIfPpDxIvDpKzRvp@rE|MrF|MhKpRbF`Ir_@jo@`LtS~MzYp[bw@hEvJ|F`LbLvQzHrJfv@fz@nUxXh`AtoAlGzIl`AbwAvMfRx_AnmAlr@z}@jQtTfJxJv]h]buDfqDjFrGbI~K|E~HpFnKlFfLzB|FjElMhCvI|T`w@vDnPzChPx@vFdBhOrh@xlFbNptAvAdMnB`MnEjT~EvQhF`O~F`NjCjFhEtHlEbHbk@bx@fWb^nSvXnSrYxGpKjDvGnDxHnHdR~_A|gCdNz]tEtMfs@zlBbHhQ|jDzoH|r@lzA|Yvk@xClFvJxRhInOhP`\hJ|PbIvOxB|E|m@plA~LpUzs@dwAvj@hfA|D|IrDrJzlAriDhFfR~Uv~@h`@j|Afy@`{DtFzX|BtOpArLvSjcCv@dNJjEGbFDdDVnElAnIx@xDnC~JbApFb@fDbKb~@`Dj^hBvN|BbO|Dl]

And this is what DefaultHandler returns:

qhitFxpifMn@t@vA`CdM`WnnBjeEtI|PlIxNxHhMjLdQ|dAlwA`~CxfEfOxRlK`O~PdUvOlTnHdJbYl\fVlW`q@~p@~gA`gAfKzKbP`Rpa@bi@|wAnuBjZ|c@rD~F`JjP|I|Qzr@`~AbKpS`J~OvGdKnPhUbMpN~{@~{@tLhMlZfZnI~Ilh@nh@nN`O~GbJjEpGpErHbIfPpDxIvDpKzRvp@rE|MrF|MhKpRbF`Ir_@jo@`LtS~MzYp[bw@hEvJ|F`LbLvQzHrJfv@fz@nUxXh`Ato

It stops at character 282 and I don't know why.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of the [ContentHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html) interface, which is implemented by DefaultHandler:

> SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks

You need to aggregate the data from multiple calls to this method in a StringBuilder and then handle that data in the endElement call.